# .Net - Registry Key Launch Condition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, registrykey

I'm trying to add a launch condition to my .msi package deployment but it's not working. I want to check if UAC is enabled in the target machine. My values for the registry search are:

```
 Property: UACSTATUS
 RegKey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
 Root: vsdrrHKLM
 Value: EnableLUA
```

The value is of a REG_DWORD type. 1 for enabled, 0 for disabled.

Then I created the launch condition:

```
 (Name): UACVerification
 Condition: UACSTATUS = 0
 InstallUrl: <left blank for now>
 Message: You must disable UAC prior to install this application.
```

The problem is: it doesn't work. Testing in my machine (which has UAC disabled), both comparisons for 0 or 1 in the Condition returns false and doesn't allow me to continue with the installation.

Aren't REG_DWORD types treated as numbers? I tried using quotes ("0", or '0') but it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the HKEY setting. Make sure that you are checking for the HKEY_CURRENT_USER? (or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE). I have run into a similar issue in the past, and if my memory is working properly, then this solved it for me.

Oh, and if this proves to be correct, then I believe the reason you are getting false is because on some of these branches, the System or UACSTATUS does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

REG_DWORD types are treated as boolean.

0 = false
1 = true